# Is 'I wish Joe would close the door after he ..............' correct?

Tags: grammar

So, which of the following sentences would be the correct answer?

> I wish Joe would close the door after he LEFT.
>
> I wish Joe would close the door after he LEAVES.
>
> I wish Joe would close the door after he LEAVE.

Comment: Please look up the verb: to leave.

Comment: when he leaves.

Answer (score -2):

> a) I wish Joe would close the door after he LEFT.
>
> b) I wish Joe would close the door after he LEAVES.
>
> c) I wish Joe would close the door after he LEAVES.

- Obviously c) is wrong since "he" is a singular third person subjective pronoun, "leave" need an "s" here.

- But this doesn't mean b) is literally correct. It may be acceptable for spoken English, but not for written English because of the phrase "I wish", which must be followed by "past tense" in order to make it assumptive.

- a) I wish Joe would close the door after he left. is the right one

Comment: This is not correct. B is the only grammatical option.

Comment: https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/wishes-and-hypotheses is my reference.

Comment: In this case, “I wish” **is** followed by a past tense form: _would_. That requirement does not extend to embedded clauses within the embedded clause.

Comment: I thought you would use past tense for the whole sentence if it stated about hypotheses being not likely to happen in the future since the OP used the word "wish" instead of "hope".

Comment: No, that’s not how it works. If it’s a wish about the present or future, you keep the sentence in the present (or future) tense; only the verb that is directly governed by _wish_ is shifted into the past tense.

Comment: I must left this here for the OP as we already discussed it. Ty @JanusBahsJacquet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84998/discussion-between-hbtpoprock-and-janus-bahs-jacquet).

Comment: "I wish Joe had closed the door after he left" (on this occasion). "I wish Joe would close the door after he leaves" (instead of habitually leaving it open).

Comment: Thank you all for this discussion. 
I'm reading English Grammar in Use and the topic was to use `wish` in a sentence. Using `hope` in a sentence is a different topic.